# How do I use Google's gapi with Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, onload, google-api-js-client

Google's gapi js library wants an onload function specified like this:

`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>`

How do I interoperate this with ReactJS?

I tried using react-script-loader (https://github.com/yariv/ReactScriptLoader) which ran into some troubles because gapi doesn't yet exist when the script loader thinks it has completed returning it.

Comment: Have you looked at NuclearMail? It's basically a gmail-clone made with flux by the Facebook engineer Ian Obermiller. Might be helpful :) https://github.com/ianobermiller/nuclearmail

Comment: That's a great link! Thanks Hummlas.

Comment: Do you know how to get the `gapi` working with `react-native`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're still looking for this answer but I faced the same problem and the best option that I found was creating this package with all gapi script code, so now I just have to import it into my react app and I doesn't even have to wait the gapi script loaded from google apis link.

[gapi-script package](https://github.com/partnerhero/gapi-script)

I also created an example showing how you can use this package:
[gapi-script example](https://github.com/LucasAndrad/gapi-script-live-example)

Comment: Hi, I'm doing a similar project to the example you just gave, How would I be able to persist the log in when I refresh? Because it shows the login button for a split second when I refresh